# i want to use value store in php variable into other file having javascript function in it

Tags: javascript, php

I want the value I get in `$re` variale to use in a Javascript function variable `var $r`:

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
if(!isLogIn()){<br>
$_SESSION['msg']="You must log in first";
header('location:login.php');
}
$orderid=$_GET['id'];
$Maxid=mysqli_query($db,"sql query here");
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($MAxid);
$re=$result['printst'];

<script type="text/javascript">
function print(){
var $r=<?php $re;?>;
if($r==1){
window.print();}
else{
return false}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use echo function to inject php result into javascript as follow:

```
include('functions.php'); 
if(!isLogIn()){
$_SESSION['msg']="You must log in first"; 
header('location:login.php');
}
$orderid=$_GET['id'];
$Maxid=mysqli_query($db,"sql query here");
$result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($MAxid);
$re=$result['printst'];

//assuming this is the javascript part
function print(){
var $r=<?php echo $re;?>;
if($r==1){
window.print();}
else{
return false}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that variable to your JS file like this

```
<script>
 var $r= '<?php echo $re; ?>';
</script>
```

// your js file use that variable

```
function print(){
if($r==1){
window.print();}
else{
return false}
```